# How to use CAEmitterLayer on macOS in a SwiftUI app using NSViewRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui, caemitterlayer, caemittercell, nsviewrepresentable

I want to use a `CAEmitterLayer` within a macOS app that is based on SwiftUI.

**Problem: The layer itself is perfectly visible, but it doesn’t emit any particles.**

[→ Here’s my demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/martinlexow/CAEmitterLayerDemo)

[image]

I basically built a `NSViewRepresentable` for a custom class `EmitterNSView: NSView` that handles the emitter layer itself.

```
final class EmitterNSView: NSView {

    private let emitterLayer: CAEmitterLayer = {
        let layer = CAEmitterLayer()
        layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.33).cgColor
        return layer
    }()

    private let emitterCells: [CAEmitterCell] = {
        // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caemitterlayer
        let cell = CAEmitterCell()
        cell.name = "someParticle"
        cell.birthRate = 10
        cell.lifetime = 5.0
        cell.velocity = 100
        cell.velocityRange = 50
        cell.emissionLongitude = 0.0
        cell.emissionRange = CGFloat.pi * 2.0
        cell.spinRange = 5
        cell.scale = 1.0
        cell.scaleRange = 0.25
        cell.alphaSpeed = 0.25
        cell.contents = NSImage(named: "whiteParticle.png")!.cgImage
        cell.color = NSColor.systemPink.cgColor
        cell.xAcceleration = 4
        cell.yAcceleration = 3
        cell.zAcceleration = 2
        return [cell]
    }()

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer = CALayer()
        self.layer?.autoresizingMask = [.layerWidthSizable, .layerHeightSizable]
        self.configureEmitterLayer()
        self.layer?.addSublayer(self.emitterLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()
        self.configureEmitterLayer()
    }

    override func updateLayer() {
        super.updateLayer()
        self.configureEmitterLayer()
    }

    func configureEmitterLayer() {
        self.emitterLayer.frame = self.frame
        self.emitterLayer.autoresizingMask = [.layerHeightSizable, .layerWidthSizable]
        self.emitterLayer.masksToBounds = false
        self.emitterLayer.drawsAsynchronously = true
        self.emitterLayer.emitterMode = .points
        self.emitterLayer.birthRate = 2
        self.emitterLayer.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.line
        self.emitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: frame.width * 0.5, height: frame.height * 0.5)
        self.emitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint.zero
        self.emitterLayer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerRenderMode.additive
        self.emitterLayer.emitterCells = self.emitterCells
        self.emitterLayer.zPosition = 10
        self.emitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        self.emitterLayer.speed = 1.5
        self.emitterLayer.emitterCells = self.emitterCells
    
    }

}
```

The fact that I can clearly see the green background of the layer within the app indicates that something is wrong with the cells? Feeling lost at this point.

Very similar implementations in `UIKit` work just fine.

**How can I use `CAEmitterLayer` on macOS within a SwiftUI based app?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cgImage(forProposedRect:context:hints:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519861-cgimage) while casting NSImage to a CGImage.

```
cell.contents = NSImage(named:"whiteParticle.png").flatMap {
    return $0.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
}
```

Comment: This approach works perfectly fine. Thank you so much @RTXGamer, I would never have thought of it on my own. So does this mean the `cgImage` property on `NSImage` is broken? Would love to understand the issue here!

Comment: @ixany There is no property as `cgImage`, do check the definition. You're calling the method `func cgImage(forProposedRect proposedDestRect: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRect>?, context referenceContext: NSGraphicsContext?, hints: [NSImageRep.HintKey : Any]?) -> CGImage?` wherein all the parameters are optional.